# How do we sum individual array elements in MongoDB aggregation query?

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
Document :
  {
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "actor": {
        "objectType": "Agent",
        "name": "Test user",
        "account": {
            "homePage": "http://testing.com/",
            "name": "67"
        }
    },
    "verb": {
        "id": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/verbs/completed",
        "display": {
            "en-US": "completed"
        }
    },
    "object": {
        "objectType": "Activity",
        "id": "http://localhost/action?id=cji",
        "definition": {
            "type": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/activities/lesson",
            "name": {
                "en-US": "ps3"
            },
            "description": {
                "en-US": "ps3"
            }
        }
    },
    "timestamp": "2016-10-25T11:21:25.917Z",
    "context": {
        "extensions": {
            "http://localhost/eventinfo": {
                "sessionId": "1477393533327",
                "starttm": "1477394351210",
                "eventtm": "1477394485917",
                "course": "cji"
            }
        },
        "contextActivities": {
            "parent": [
                {
                    "objectType": "Activity",
                    "id": "http://localhost/id=cji"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "result": {
        "duration": "PT2M14.71S",
        "score": {
            "raw": 6,
            "max": 21
        }
    },
    "authority": {
        "objectType": "Agent",
        "name": "New Client",
        "mbox": "mailto:hello@lhd.net"
    },
    "stored": "2016-10-25T11:20:29.666700+00:00",
    "id": "c7039783-371f-4f59-a665-65a9d09a2b7f"
}

We've got this PHP + MongoDB aggregation query:

    $condition = array(
                 array(
                '$match' => array(
                    'client_id' => $CFG->mongo_clientid,
                    'statement.actor.account.name' => array('$in'=> array('67','192','213')),
                    'statement.verb.id' => 'http://adlnet.gov/expapi/verbs/completed',
                    'statement.object.id' => 'http://localhost/action?id=cji'
                )),
                 array(
                '$group' => array(
                    '_id' =>  '$statement.actor.account.name' ,
                    //'totalpoints' =>array( '$sum' => array('$last' => '$statement.result.score.raw'))                
                    'laststatement' => array('$last' => '$statement.result.score.raw'),
                    //'sumtest' => array('$add' => ['$laststatement'])
                     )
                  )
            );
             $cursor = $collection->aggregate($condition);
             echo "";
             print_r($cursor);
             echo "";

which returns this result:

    Array
    (
        [result] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [_id] => 192
                        [laststatement] => MongoInt64 Object
                            (
                                [value] => 4
                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [_id] => 67
                        [laststatement] => MongoInt64 Object
                            (
                                [value] => 6
                            )

                    )

            )

        [ok] => 1
    )
```

How do we sum `[laststatement].[value]` of these individual array elements in MongoDB aggregation query?

```
[laststatement] => MongoInt64 Object
                        (
                            [value] => values goes here
                        )
```

Also, how do we use `$last` and `$sum` together in MongoDB aggregation query?
In my result there are 2 raw scores(last statement) for 2 different id (192,67). I want to sum this scores like 4 + 6 = 10 for all multiple id's but want only the last scores from the last statement. I am unable to use $last and $sum on the line. Please check

Comment: Do you want to sum and result in a single group ? Please add data structure if you can.

Comment: Added document to the question. Please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like all you want is a single group. So the grouping id should be null. You may want to add a sort if you care for what last record should be. Not tested.

```
array(
      '$group' => array(
      '_id' =>  null ,
      'totalpoints' => array( '$sum' => '$statement.result.score.raw')                
      'laststatement' => array('$last' => '$statement.result.score.raw')
     )
)
```

Here is the mongo shell version.

```
aggregate([
    {
       $match :{
             "actor.account.name":{$in:["67","192","213"]},
             "verb.id":{$eq:"http://adlnet.gov/expapi/verbs/completed"},
             "object.id":{$eq:"http://localhost/action?id=cji"}
       }
    },
    {
      $group: {
          "_id": null,
          "totalpoints" : {$sum:"$result.score.raw"},                
          "laststatement" :{$last:"$result.score.raw"}
      }
    }
])
```

Output:

```
{ "_id" : null, "totalpoints" : 10, "laststatement" : 4 }
```

**Update** Changed to include the sum for the last statement from each group. The first grouping is by actor name and returns the last statement from each group. The second grouping sums all the last statement.

```
aggregate([{
    $match: {
        "actor.account.name": {
            $in: ["67", "192", "213"]
        },
        "verb.id": {
            $eq: "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/verbs/completed"
        },
        "object.id": {
            $eq: "http://localhost/action?id=cji"
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        "_id": "$actor.account.name",
        "laststatement": {
            $last: "$result.score.raw"
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        "_id": null,
        "totalpoints": {
            $sum: "$laststatement"
        },
    }
}])
```

Comment: this is producing an output for only user 67 and giving total of all statements generated by 67 and it is coming as 60. we want the total of last statements of 67,192 and total is not coming as 10

Comment: Updated the answer based on previous comment. Please verify.

Comment: Thank you @Veeram it solved my problem, 
Now i am stuck in another query. Updated the question with the new issues.